# A contractor tells me even if he seals the attic, raccoons will break in anyway if they smell old raccoon smells. True? Urgent?

Tags: repair, attic, pest

We had raccoons in the attic in spring for the past few years. We've finally nearly arrived at a point where we can do something to prevent them from getting in. We've had one estimate so far, and they gave us an estimate for sealing up the house and also for fixing up the attic, repairing and removing the animal's traces, etc.

They talked up the fixing up part (the prohibitively expensive part) as urgent, saying if we didn't do that, then the raccoons would be attracted to the various smells left behind by past raccoons and would basically force their way in, tearing holes in the walls/roof once more, requiring the house to get sealed up once again next year.

I am interested to know opinions about whether that is a genuinely urgent issue (raccoons forcing their way into an attic that has had wildlife entry points repaired), or whether that is a case of the home repair professional feeling a lot more urgency about things than is actually financially necessary for homeowners, because it's the pro's specialty and because it means money to them.

We obviously will get it repaired eventually but the prohibitive cost means I need to figure out if it can wait or if it's really true that not fixing the attic interior will lead to raccoons practically immediately breaking new holes to get in etc.

We're also, btw, going to be getting the trees cut away that wildlife might be using to more easily get up on the roof so, hopefully, that may cut down on the likelihood as well?

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: I can see a mother trying to get in if her babies are trap inside or they are starving and smell food or one is trapped inside and tries to get out.  Otherwise they go for easier pickings.

Comment: Had a pregnant critter (racoon, I think) crawl down an unused chimney and give birth. After a couple of sleepless nights hearing the babies scratching against the inside of the chimney, I got a chimney sweep brush, climbed up on the roof and poked at them all. 24 hours later, she'd moved everyone out. I gave it another couple of days to be sure, then put a chimney cap on. Never had any additional issues. Nobody appeared to be fighting to get through the chimney cap just because there were animal smells down there...